# How can I reduce the number of arguments with this "printf" function? Should I be using something other than "printf"?

Tags: c

I'm having an issue that I've been attempting to solve. I understand the difference between printf and puts, so I figured that printf was the correct way to go here.

However, I get an error that says:

"warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

```
printf("%s", "The sum of %d", first , " and %d", second, " is %d", first + second);
^"
```

Is there a better function to print the output I need or perhaps a different way to format this one?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int first, second;
    int answer = 1;

    while (answer == 1)
    {
        puts("Please enter the first integer ==> ");
        scanf("%d", &first);

        puts("Please enter the second integer ==> ");
        scanf("%d", &second);

        printf("%s", "The sum of %d", first , " and %d", second, " is %d", first + second);

        puts("Would you like to add two more integers?\n"
              "(1 for yes) ==> ");
              scanf("%d", &answer);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you search for "printf example" you immediately spot your error.

Comment: You might want to look at the docs for printf and/or search for a quick tutorial--it's almost always faster to just do some research instead of waiting for someone to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string must be the first argument of `printf` and your inputs must be the following ones. For example:

```
printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d", first, second, first + second);
```